# Azure Pipeline : getting error while deploying application to tomcat server in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy my java application to tomcat server using Azure DevOps Release pipeline.
I have filled the path for war file, server URL information, username and password in the tomcat server tab like below :

[image: Deploy application to a tomcat server]

But deployment is getting failed and I am getting below error :

[image: tomcat error]

Am I using the path or any other information wrong?
Can anybody please help me with this, thank you.

Comment: You seem to have white spaces in the path. Don't do that, or at least quote them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the path of the `WAR File` you specified is incorrect, which caused the file cannot be found.

I reproduced the exactly same error, if i specified an incorrect war file path. When i entered the right **war file** path. The error was gone. See below:

The correct file path should be `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Tomcat/drop/Build CS&S2/SizingAndSelection2 WAR/target/sample.war`:

[image]

You can go the release Logs to check the log of the `Download artifacts` to see where the war file has been downloaded.

[image]

Or you can click the **3dots** of the `War file field` to locate the war file in the artifact. See below

[image]

Comment: Thank You for  you post  Levi Lu-MSFT, it solved the issue. path of the war file was wrong, I changed the path and it fixed the issue.